# Passing string/ character argument when writing a function in R

Tags: r, string, function, character

For example, I'm trying to write this function that converts a probability table into data.frame in R. I want the argument "na" to be the first colname of this data frame.

```
  prop_table_to_df <- function(table, nm){
     data.frame(nm = factor(names(table)), Percentage = table)
  }
```

Suppose I call a function (sk_table, "age_group")
The expected out output is this

```
        age_group Percentage
(15,20]   (15,20]  0.4518717
(20,25]   (20,25]  0.3118461
(25,30]   (25,30]  0.2136201
(30,35]   (30,35]  0.1863965
```

But instead the output is

```
             nm   Percentage
(15,20]   (15,20]  0.4518717
(20,25]   (20,25]  0.3118461
(25,30]   (25,30]  0.2136201
(30,35]   (30,35]  0.1863965
```

How do I fix this? Apparently, in this situation, R doesn't accept string or character as an argument when wrting the function. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You could try with `setnames` : e.g. `setnames(data.frame(factor(names(table)), table), c("age_group", "Percentage"))`, where the 'age_group' is the string you pass into the function.

Comment: @SymbolixAU `setnames` is data.table. The base is `setNames`; `set_names` is matrittr/purrr.

Comment: @alistaire - yes, you're right - I use `data.table` everyday that for me it counts as base :~)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add another line to do the renaming after making the data.frame. I've done that below, renaming the first column of the new df to the function input nm.

```
prop_table_to_df <- function(table, nm){
    df = data.frame(nm = factor(names(table)), Percentage = table)
    colnames(df)[1] = nm #rename first column to value of nm
    return(df)
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I did! Thank you! I just wonder if there's a more direct way to write it without data.table way.